# Weired animation of tableview and searchbar of UISearchController embed in navigationbar

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uisearchbar, ios13

I've embed UISearchController into the navigationbar and my view controller has the table view. When I click on searchbar and keyboard appears tableview and searchbar does not animate smoothly. It seems like searchbar is overlaping navigationbar.

Here is the code,

Declare searchcontroller as a variable like,

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
```

and defination in viewDidLoad is like,

```
self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
        self.navigationItem.searchController = controller
        return controller
    })()
```

Animation issue is like below gif(watch till end to see slow animation)

[image]

I want same duration for animation for tableview, navigation bar, and searchbar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set `UITableView` top anchor to be pinned to `safeArea` but to `superview`.

Comment: Omg! Perfect! It was a silly thing that I haven't considered. Just pinned top with superview instead of safe area and solved. There is no connection with isTranslucent btw. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Important extra note to the accepted answer:
If you use a `UIViewController` with subviews, including a `UITableView`, the `UITableView` has to be the first subview (i.e.: at index 0).

Answer (score 0):

In my case **disabling** `Use Safe Area Layout Guides` for `UIViewController` checkbox in storyboard fixed the issue .

After disabling it **make sure**:

- `Top Layout Guide`'s bottom - must be constrainted to the most top subview from your viewController.
- `Bottom Layout Guide`' top - must be constrainted to the most bottom subview from viewController.

P.S.
This is also fixes problem with `scopeBar` animation issue.
I figured this out by using this article's materials. MasterViewController is Main.storyboard. If you are confused you can check it out yourself.

https://www.kodeco.com/4363809-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

[image]